# python lxml xpath cannot parse apostrophe quote

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am trying to read a parameter from an XML file with folowing path:

parameter path in xml = "node1/node2/param's name"

```
parser = etree.parse(xml_file_path, etree.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8', recover=True, huge_tree=True))
parser.xpath("./SPLIT/NODE[contains(text(), 'node1')]/SPLIT/NODE[contains(text(), 'node2')]/SPLIT/NODE[contains(text(), 'param's name')]")
```

Due to a single quote in the node name, I am getting this eeror - {XPathEvalError}Invalid Expression
The same code works fine if there is no single quote.

I tried finding the solution in lxml xpath documentation but could not find any mechanism to skip this single quote.
I did find a similar qustion but it does not have any answer.
I also tried replacing single quote with ' but didn't work.
Please let me know if there is a way to skip single quote or if I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: have you tried `parser.xpath("""./SPLIT/NODE[contains(text(), 'node1')]/SPLIT/NODE[contains(text(), 'node2')]/SPLIT/NODE[contains(text(), "param's name")]""")`. In short you can try `.//NODE[text()="node1/node2/param's name"]`

Comment: @supputuri Thanks! it worked. Need to find a way to flip the single quotes to double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below options.

```
parser.xpath("""./SPLIT/NODE[contains(text(), "node1")]/SPLIT/NODE[contains(text(), "node2")]/SPLIT/NODE[contains(text(), "param's name")]""")
```

In short

```
.//NODE[text()="node1/node2/param's name"]
```

Comment: Added the same content from comment, so that you can accept and close this question.